# Uma requisição http em uma página JSP abre uma sessão?

Tags: jsf-2.2, session, jsp

Tenho uma aplicação web que contém algumas páginas JSP que retornam um JSON.

Esta aplicação tem um grande fluxo de acessos, e notei que há muitas sessões abertas na área de monitoramento do servidor GlassFish.

Veja um pedaço de código que está na JSP:

```
 <%
      RequestLive ao vivo = new RequestLive ();
      out.print (live.search ());
 %>
```

Isso é tudo que eu tenho no JSP, o resto da classe Java faz o serviço, e o JSON é impresso na página.

A verdadeira questão é, uma sessão é aberta se eu acessar a URL para recuperar os dados?

> Ex: www.mydomain.com/RequestLive.jsp

Devo chamar o `session.invalidade ();` ou está correto como estou utilizando?

Comment: A pergunta foi traduzida!

Comment: O que `live.seach()` faz? Depois de impresso o que a pessoa faz? Vai ler e copiar ou é somente para consumir em outras aplicações? Se isto for um restService, seria interessante fazer em um Servlet.

Comment: Faz uma pesquisa e retorna em um JSON, a página funciona como um REST sim...

Answer (score 0):

Se é um "RestService" que quer faça algo assim:

```
import java.io.IOException;  
import java.io.PrintWriter;  
import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;  
import javax.servlet.ServletException;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;  
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;  
import org.json.JSONArray;  
import org.json.JSONException;  
import org.json.JSONObject;  
import br.com.dominio.Pessoa;  
public class PessoaServlet extends HttpServlet {       
       private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;  

       @Override  
       protected void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
            recuperarPessoas(request, response);  
       }  
       @Override  
       protected void doPost(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  
            recuperarPessoas(request, response);  
       }  
       private void recuperarPessoas(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {  
            try {  
                 request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");  
        response.setContentType("application/json");   
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();   
                 List<Pessoa> procedimentos = getPessoas();  
                 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();  
                 for (Pessoa obj : procedimentos) {  
                      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();  
                      jsonObject.put("nome", obj.getNome());  
                      jsonObject.put("idade", obj.getIdade());  
                      jsonArray.put(jsonObject);  
                 }  
                 out.print(jsonArray);  
            } catch (JSONException e) {  
                 e.printStackTrace();  
            }  
       }  
       private List<Pessoa> getPessoas() {  
            List<Pessoa> pessoas = new ArrayList<Pessoa>();  
            Pessoa pessoaUm = new Pessoa();  
            pessoaUm.setNome("Gustavo Lopes de Oliveira");  
            pessoaUm.setIdade(25);  
            Pessoa pessoaDois = new Pessoa();  
            pessoaDois.setNome("Ralph Miranda");  
            pessoaDois.setIdade(28);  
            pessoas.add(pessoaUm);  
            pessoas.add(pessoaDois);  
            return pessoas;  
       }  
  }
```

Fonte: [JSON SERVLET](http://gustavlopes.blogspot.com.br/2013/08/exemplo-de-json-servlet-ajax-jquery.html)

Ou então você pode usar Frameworks que ajudam a desenvolver REST Service, Spring MVC etc.